# How to publish sphinx-generated documentation on bitbucket wiki automatically?

Tags: bitbucket, python-sphinx

I have a python package with sphinx-generated documentation (using the automodules feature) and it can be made into a set of static html pages sitting in a _build directory in the git repository of the project. I would like to view this documentation in pretty and *private* way on bitbucket. It seems the wiki which is a git repo itself might be usable for that.

Is there an easy step of sequences that can make/convert my html documentation into markup and push it to the bitbucket wiki repository?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not really possible...

You can push your _build dir to the wiki repo and create links in the wiki (Home.rst) to your html files like so:

```
`Sphinx docs <_build/html/index.html>`_
```

And it will display them but inclusion of _static css/js files won't work, so your docs will look ugly :(

You could also [publish your docs as a website on BitBucket](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Publishing+a+Website+on+Bitbucket) but there's no privacy, your docs will be public even if your repo is private, so this is not very useful, then you can just go with [read the docs](https://readthedocs.org/)...

Read the docs actually [supports privacy](http://docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/privacy.html) so you could add your docs in a private mode and add a [Webhook](http://docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/webhooks.html#bitbucket) in BitBucket. This unfortunately only works with public repos so not a great solution either...

P.S. There's a reusable app that allows you to privately serve your sphinx docs from django (protected): [django-docs](http://django-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) ;)
And you can build those from your bitbucket *.rst files...

Comment: That looks like a thorough summary of the state of affairs. Thanks.

Comment: This looks like it's still valid as of today

Comment: This is still valid as of today too. **Jan 2020**

Comment: Still seems valid as of today Dec 2021

Answer (score 0):

You are able to include custom css files in the static folder. Also you can convert to Myst using rst2myst.
(pip install rst-to-myst[sphinx]